Do I need to validate a Genoa MET daily ticket every time?
I hold a MET Daily ticket, that I validated on the metro the first time
Do I need to continue to validate it every time I take a bus/metro?

I think you need to validate only once (so you get the date and time: it is valid 24h).

Il biglietto deve essere convalidato e conservato per tutta la durata ed esibito al personale di verifica in caso di controllo.

source: Biglietto 24 ore MetDaily, and I would translate it as:

The ticket must be validated and kept for the entire validity period, and be shown to crew in case of a ticket check.

Not the best way to write it, but I think I get the meaning of such "bureaucratic speech".

That is how the 24h tickets work in Berlin.

In many places you have to validate your ticket every time you enter the metro or board a bus/tram, I think essentially for stats.

@jcaron: yes, but I see the convalidato as just first time. Also here in Switzerland (and I know also in Italy) tickets are stamped: if you do twice you will not see the date and time. There is some aversion on to much technological magic and on bus I think it will cost too much to adapt such system (on a country where lack of money on public transportation is a sensible argument).

@GiacomoCatenazzi Ah indeed, if it's a printed paper ticket, obviously you should validate it only once...

No, the ticket is validated only by first marking. It prints the starting moment (and place sometimes) and sets since when, and where, it is valid from.
The end of the period is marked by the type of the ticket. A daily ticket is valid for 24 hours since validation.
Any other attempt to validate it again will render it invalid instantly. Two timestamps are understood as cheating.
You may be asked to show the ticket to the staff/driver.
The only case you might need to re-validate is: There is no other way to get in the metro/tram/bus than stuff the ticket in the tourniket.

When bought online, it doesn't need validation (to my understanding) since it states a start date and time.
I intend to buy one for my upcoming trip from Genoa to Portofino but I don't understand if it includes the train to Santa Margherita Ligure.
Well I'll have to buy it there instead of online buying.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
